# How to use LDAP from .NET

Tags: ldap

I would like to get the groups a user belongs to.

Although I got this to work as a test with
`DirectoryServices` I cannot do that in reality  because the code runs in container (Unix).

So I am trying to use a `Nuget` package https://github.com/flamencist/ldap4net and trying out a small test code first in my Windows workstation.

```
using (var cn = new LdapConnection())
{
    cn.Connect(host, port);
 
    var who = "uuu";
    var password = "ppp";
    cn.Bind(LdapAuthType.Negotiate, new LdapCredential
    {
        Realm = "dc=abc,dc=com",
        UserName = who,
        Password = password
    });
    
    //....

}
```

But in the call to `Bind` I am getting an exception `Unwilling To Perform. Unwilling To Perform. Result: 53. Method: BindSasl`

Can anyone please help about getting this to work?